# Problemas con la etiqueta Image de React

Tags: reactjs

Verán, quiero mostrar en mi proyecto imágenes almacenadas en una carpeta de mi proyecto.
Normalmente hago esto:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import arranque from '../images/arranque.png';

const Inicio = () => {
  return (
    <main className="Wrap">
      <h1>
        <u>¡Bienvenido a los Concesionarios Max!</u>
      </h1>
      <p>
        ¿Buscas un coche de última gama? ¿Uno barato? ¿Uno con mucho espacio?
        <br />
        Sea cual sea el coche que estes buscando, ¡Aquí lo encontrarás!
      </p>
      <Link to="/coche">
        <button className="VcButton">Lista de Coches</button>
      </Link>
      <ul>
        <img src={arranque} alt="Error" />
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Inicio;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen se muestra, pero no puedo estar para cada imagen importándola, pues imaginemos que estoy mirando la variable `foto` de una tabla SQL...
Buscando por internet, me encontré con que mi solución eran las etiquetas react:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

const Inicio = () => {
  return (
    <main className="Wrap">
      <h1>
        <u>¡Bienvenido a los Concesionarios Max!</u>
      </h1>
      <p>
        ¿Buscas un coche de última gama? ¿Uno barato? ¿Uno con mucho espacio?
        <br />
        Sea cual sea el coche que estes buscando, ¡Aquí lo encontrarás!
      </p>
      <Link to="/coche">
        <button className="VcButton">Lista de Coches</button>
      </Link>
      <ul>
        <Image source={require('../images/arranque.png')} />
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Inicio;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero parece que algo falla que me causa este error. Instale en la carpeta client de mi proyecto el react-native, pero el mensaje da a entender que el proyecto no lo detecta. ¿Que me estará fallando?

Actualizo: Esta es la foto que uso y la ruta donde está.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta en client/src/images.

Más información: He añadido webpack en la carpeta client mediante yarn add webpack, después cree un fichero webpack.config.js en la carpeta client.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho fichero tiene el siguiente código:

```
import ExtractTextWebpackPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin('app.bundle.css')],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Pero aún no se cargan las imágenes. ¿Que más necesito?

Más datos: Me he hizo a la etiqueta client y he añadido file loader mediante `yarn add file-loader`. Después he modificado webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Pero aún no se carga mi imagen. Aunque ahora me aparece un error en la terminal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece un error con el proxy. Este es el archivo package.json, donde aparece al principio la mención al proxy 6000:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:6000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tal y como aparece, hace la llamada al localhost:6000. El server usa un port a 5001, y el client a 3000.

Aparte, este es el estilo de las imágenes, que esta en un fichero llamado _page.scss:

```
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Cómo es la estructura de archivos de la aplicación? Y `react-image.png` no es `arranque.png`. Borraste una imagen y aun tienes la referencia?

Comment: @milmal he añadido más información, a ver si así lo entiendes mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programas de ReactNative son applicaciones para dispositivos mobiles, no se puede usar directamente entre codigo de React.js, aun son vecinos technologicamente.

Para alcanzar lo que estas intentando de lograr, mejor es de usar WebPack on unos trucos especiales y ya, puedes usar imagenes dinamicamente.

Truco primero:

```
const imagen = './gato.png'  
<img src={require(`${imagen}`)} alt="producto" />
```

En eso, observa el uso de puntuacion con el nombre de variable `imagen`. Todos los puntuaciones se necesitan, para el WebPack lo entienda.

Truco segundo, lo que hace todo vivo:

```
{
     test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
     use: [
         {
             loader: 'file-loader',
             options: {}
         }
     ]
 }
```

Eso se pone en webpack.config.js para que el entienda sobre imagenes de tipos `png`, `jpg` y `gif`.

Un webpack configuracion completo sera algo asi:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin =  require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry : './src/app.js',
  output : {
    path : './dist',
    filename : 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  plugins : [
  new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin('app.bundle.css')],
  module : {
    rules : [{
      test : /\.css$/,
      use : ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract({
        fallback : 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader'
      })
    },{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react','es2015']
      }
    },{
      test :  /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader : 'file-loader'
    }]
  }
}
```

**Mis fuentes de informacion desde SO en ingles:**

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612912/dynamically-add-images-react-webpack/45272215#45272215

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js/49712783#49712783

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947474/dynamically-loading-local-images-with-reactjs/46079722#46079722

[4] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs/45334965#45334965

**Mas informacion sobre WebPack (y Babel cual es tambien en mi configuracion de ejemplo):**

[5] https://medium.com/@yabikusensei/configurar-babel-webpack-loaders-plugins-y-linter-javascript-d1ed1b5e5a88

**Tambien, file-loader usado se encuentra de aqui:**

[6] https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

**Editando:**

```
|
 - images
     |
      - arranque.png
|
 - src
     |
     pages
       |
        - Inicio.js
```

Asi estan tus ficheros. Entonces la referencia desde Inicio.js sera como `../../images/arranque.png` entonces el todito sera:

```
<img src={require('../../images/arranque.png')} />
```

**Todavia:**

Asi que entiendo, el proxy esta usado cuando conectas al servidor con el comando `require`. Entonces, tengas

```
<img src={require('/images/arranque.png')} />
```

y el proxy lo dirige al localhost:6000 en lado del localhost:3000 donde estas con client. Eso `servidor:puerta` combinacion puede ser cual quiera y todo funciona sin modificar el codigo entre dev y prod cuando usas diferente valor de proxy.

Puede ser que el proxy esta ahora tomando tu `../images/arranque.png` como un destinacion a fuera al servidor y intentando de applicar el valor `localhost:6000` a el por eso.

Yo sacare fuera el proxy y tomare un prueba otra vez. Recuerda el `require()` alrededor del direccion de imagen `require('./images/arranque.png')` o

```
const imagen = './images/arranque.png'  
<img src={require(`${imagen}`)} alt="producto" />
```

, si quieras que el nombre viene de base de datos o variable.

**A ver, todavia:**

Yo hacia un ejemplo en mi computadora para saber exactamente que sucede. Tenia que usar el tag asi para funcionar:

```
<img src={require('../images/arranque.png').default} />
```

sin el default palabra, venia solo un marco de [object Module] en dev tools y un imagen roto a la pantalla.

Mi ejemplo esta cargada al Github:

[7] https://github.com/micoFinlandes/reactjs-webpack/tree/master

Comment: Hablas de un fichero webpack.config.js, ¿Y donde está en mi proyecto? Porque estoy viendo que hay varios ficheros que se llaman asi.

Comment: Eao cual es directamente abajo se client. Mira recurso [3].

Comment: Es extraño. He buscado en mi carpeta client y no hay ni rastro de ese fichero.

Comment: Si no lo tienes, hay que crearlo. Puede ser que no lo uses el webpack todavia, por eso el configuracion tampoco. Por eso tenho el vinculo [5] paras Como utilizar webpack.

Comment: He añadido más datos.

Comment: Ya añadiste el file-loader [6]? Tambien, el Babel conf esta incluido en Webpack, seguiendo el [5] lo lograras.

Comment: así he hecho, pero no ha arreglado mi problema. He actualizado para incluir que me ha pasado ahora.

Comment: Tengo mas informacion en respuesta.

Comment: No ha funcionado. De hecho, te equivocas, primero tengo la carpeta src y dentro tengo las carpetas pages e images. No tengo por un lado images y por otro src como pones en tu esquema.

Comment: Nada mas estoy seguiendo que esta pasando. El error dice sobre proxy y no veo ningun configuracion tuyo sobre proxy. Me parece, que es una problema cual necesita nueva pregunta, para que otros puedan ayudar. Estoy vacio de ideas ahora.

Comment: Vale, he añadido información sobre el proxy. Espero que te sea util.

Comment: Todavia. Una vez mas informacion sobre la tema en respuesta.

Comment: Lo he puesto como <img src={require('../images/pieza.jpg')} alt="producto" /> y aún sigue sin ser detectado.

Comment: A ver, una vez tenia un imagen desaparecido por no definir el width y height attributos. Los marcas inicialmente a 50 y 50 y veras que pasa?

Comment: Los he marcado así y no ha funcionado. He ampliado la información.

Comment: A ver, tengo ahora ejemplo en mi maquina que funciona. Vea respuesta.

Comment: ¡Al fin! Fue solamente añadir lo de .default y ha funcionado.